# Finding Lie algebra of Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given the matrix $S ∈ M_n (\Bbb C)$ then the following forms a lie group $$G= \{ a ∈ M_n (\Bbb C)| aSa^† =S \}$$
I'm completely lost on how to find the Lie algebra of this group.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to pick a path $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to G$ such that $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\gamma'(0) = A$ for some matrix $A$.  Observe that

$$
\gamma(t)S \gamma^\dagger(t) \;\; =\;\; S.
$$

Take the derivative of both sides and evaluate at $t=0$.  See what constraints you get for $A$.